# XCTest with multi targets project

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing, tdd, xctest

I have a XCode(in Swift) project with multi targets.  Each target has its own macro that program can know which target is being run.

For example,

- FreeVersion target has a macro "FREE"
- PaidVersion target has a macro "PAID"

I would like to make test code with XCTest but it seems like XCTest source cannot be related to a specific target.

What is the best practice for using XCTest in such a situation?

Comment: Create two corresponding Unit Test bundles - and share unit tests code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the test bundle *is* associated with a specific app target through the TEST_HOST build setting. So I think it should be possible to set up two test targets. Each can have its own prefix header (pch) to set the macro you need, and specify their TEST_HOST.

If you duplicate your current test target, be sure to check the new build settings carefully. I've found that Xcode likes to change some settings in the duplicate but not others.

Comment: So do i have to add pch files manually? I added a macro flag in build setting of duplicated test target and I could't make it wokrk.